# Design one custom view, used for many ViewController's

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project, I want to access the location always. If the user is giving the permission for accessing location as **Only while using** application, I want to show a custom designed `alertView` with one button, and then click on that button the user will navigate to apps settings screen to change the location permission. I want this same alert view in many `ViewControllers`. How it makes possible?

My code:

```
- (IBAction)changetoAlwaysClicked:(id)sender {
    _locationView.hidden = YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    }];
}
```

[image]
Any help is much appreciated..!

Comment: ya its possible, show your tried code

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778603/show-uialertcontroller-from-a-common-utility-class

Comment: I just design my alert view in a view controller, and I show in that viewcontroller. I need to reuse same design in other viewControllers

Comment: see the above comment

Comment: If you have designed already then create that class object whenever you want to show alert.

Comment: @Anbu I update the question. I want to show a Custom alert view.

Comment: @VinuJacob - good, add some additional or show your tried code

Comment: @ Anbu I just Hide and Unhide this view depending on the condition.

Comment: with out code or something how can we help to you

Comment: @Anbu I update the questoin with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this can be correctly solved by creating an xib, in that file create the view that you want (or in this case you just move it). Add a ViewController as well and put the required logic for your alert there.

Then in any viewcontroller that you require it, you just need to call it like this.

```
CustomAlertViewController *customVC = [[CustomAlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:'CustomAlertViewControllerNAME' bundle:nil];
customVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
customVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; //or any other animation that you want

[self presentViewController:customVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's important to set the view outlet of your CustomViewController to make this work.

Also if you don't want to show certain properties in certain viewcontrollers you can create an enum and make the proper changes by just passing the correct enum value.

First define the enum

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int, CustomAlertViewControllerMode) {
    CustomAlertViewControllerModeExample1 = 0,
    CustomAlertViewControllerModeExample2 = 1,
};
```

in your header file add the property

```
@property CustomAlertViewControllerMode mode;
```

then when you call it, you just add this line before the presentViewController method

```
[customVC setMode:CustomAlertViewControllerModeExample1];
```

Then internally in your CustomViewController hide the required views if needed based on the enum value.